# What is difference between Table scan and seq scan in greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I created a table Year1 and inserted data into it using Generate_series.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS YEAR1;
CREATE TABLE YEAR1
(
   ID        BIGSERIAL NOTNULL,
   DAT_YEAR     INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO YEAR1 (DAT_YEAR)
SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(1,10000);
```

After creating and inserting data, I ran the below query with legacy and PQO optimizer

```
SET OPTIMIZER=OFF;
EXPLAIN 
SELECT MAX(DAT_YEAR) FROM YEAR1;

SET OPTIMIZER=ON;
EXPLAIN 
SELECT MAX(DAT_YEAR) FROM YEAR1;
```

Below is the query plan I got

[image]

Can someone explain what is the difference between Seq scan and Table Scan. I heard that both are same. If both are same then why the cost is different.

If I insert 0.1M data into Year1 table then cost of Table scan is not changing but changing for Seq scan

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The cost models used by the two optimizers are different.

For instance, the Table scan for GPORCA will almost always have a cost of 431, while that of the legacy query optimizer is variable.

These numbers make sense within a particular optimizer, but they are not comparable between the two different optimizers.

Comment: How to know which optimizer is best in these cases? Do we have to compare the execution plans of both optimizer's and decide based on that?

Comment: Are you saying cost of Table scan will be same irrespective of number of records in a table?

Comment: The plan forward is to use the new optimizer.

GP5 will have optimizer enabled by default and it will fall back to the default planner if it comes across something it cannot handle.

And yes, the optimizer has some costs fixed (based on size) due to the differences in the coding and plan generation.